# Should I keep instance variables in Java always initialized or not?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I recently started a new project and I'm trying to keep my instance variables always initialized to some value, so none of them is at any time null. Small example below:

```
public class ItemManager {

  ItemMaster itemMaster;
  List<ItemComponentManager> components;

  ItemManager() {
    itemMaster = new ItemMaster();
    components = new ArrayList<ItemComponentManager>();
  }

  ...
}
```

The point is mainly to avoid the tedious checking for *null* before using an instance variable somewhere in the code. So far, it's working good and you mostly don't need the *null*-value as you can check also for empty string or empty list, etc. I'm not using this approach for method scoped variables as their scope is very limited and so doesn't affect other parts of the code.

This all is kind of experimental, so I'd like to know if this approach could work or if there are some pitfalls which I'm not seeing yet. Is it generally a good idea to keep instance variables initialized?

Comment: Never create an empty ArrayList just to throw it away later. Always use one of the methods in the Collections class to get an empty, immutable collection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually treat an empty collection and a null collection as two separate things:

An empty collection implies that I know there are zero items available. A null collection will tell me that I don't know the state of the collection, which is a different thing.

So I really do not think it's an either/or.  And I would declare the variable **final** if I initialize them in the constructor. If you declare it final it becomes very clear to the reader that this collection cannot be null.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, **all** non-final instance variables must be declared **private** if you want to retain control!

Consider lazy instantiation as well -- this also avoids "bad state" but only initializes upon use:

```
class Foo {
    private List<X> stuff;
    public void add(X x) {
        if (stuff == null)
            stuff = new ArrayList<X>();
        stuff.add(x);
    }
    public List<X> getStuff() {
        if (stuff == null)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(stuff);
    }
}
```

(Note the use of Collections.unmodifiableList -- unless you really want a caller to be able to add/remove from your list, you should make it immutable)

Think about how many instances of the object in question will be created. If there are many, and you always create the lists (and might end up with many empty lists), you could be creating many more objects than you need.

Other than that, it's really a matter of taste and if you can have meaningful values when you construct.

If you're working with a DI/IOC, you want the framework to do the work for you (though you could do it through constructor injection; I prefer setters)
-- Scott

Comment: Really, you think all member variables should be private? Protected, yes. Private, no. what about subclassing?

Comment: Subclasses could set them to null.

Comment: Instance fields should be private for proper encapsulation, never protected.

Comment: I should clarify that I meant all non-static instance variables.

Subclasses should access them the same way other classes do - through accessors. This allows the base class to keep its state consistent.

Comment: (d'oh - I meant non-final. Need my morning wakie drugs)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that is totally fine - just as long as you remember that you have "empty" placeholder values there and not real data.

Keeping them null has the advantage of forcing you to deal with them - otherwise the program crashes. If you create empty objects, but forget them you get undefined results.

And just to comment on the defencive coding - If you are the one creating the objects and are never setting them null, there is no need to check for null every time. If for some reason you get null value, then you know something has gone catastrophically wrong and the program should crash anyway.

Comment: I second the critical opinion on defensive coding.  All too often "defensive" only hides logic errors, and I've often seen defensive gone-bad.  Much less often I'd problems with a fail-fast attitude.

Comment: "defensive" shouldn't hide any logically errors with proper error reporting. If you check for null and report an error if null is encountered then you're being defensive and you can spot logical errors quickly and easily without potentially killing a production application.

Answer (score 2):

I would make them **final** if possible. Then they have to be initialized in the constructor and cannot become null.

You should also make them private in any case, to prevent other classes from assigning null to them. If you can check that null is never assigned in your class then the approach will work.

Comment: final!? This makes it difficult to do any adhoc (de)serialization. Persisting to a db becomes difficult. Extending the class becomes a pain as well.

Comment: @Pat YAGNI (you ain't gonna need it). Subclasses can't access private state of a superclass anyway, and that is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across some cases where this causes problems.
During deserialization, some frameworks will not call the constructor, I don't know how or why they choose to do this but it happens. This can result in your values being `null`. I have also come across the case where the constructor is called but for some reason member variables are not initialized.

In actual fact I'd use the following code instead of yours:

```
public class ItemManager {

  ItemMaster itemMaster = new ItemMaster();
  List<ItemComponentManager> components = new ArrayList<ItemComponentManager>();

  ItemManager() {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I deal with any variable I declare is to decide if it will change over the lifetime of the object (or class if it is static).  If the answer is "no" then I make it final.

Making it final forces you to give it a value when the object is created... personally I would do the following unless I knew that I would be changing what the point at:

```
  private final ItemMaster itemMaster;
  private final List components;

  // instance initialization block - happens at construction time
  {
      itemMaster = new ItemMaster();
      components = new ArrayList();
  }
```

The way your code is right now you must check for null all the time because you didn't mark the variables as private (which means that any class in the same package can change the values to null).

Comment: Or just
private final ItemMaster itemMaster = new ItemMaster();
private final List components = new ArrayList();

Comment: I like to keep the initialization separate from the declration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very good idea to initialize all class variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> The point is mainly to avoid the
>   tedious checking for null before using
>   a class variable somewhere in the
>   code.

You still have to check for null. Third party libraries and even the Java API will sometimes return null.

Also, instantiating an object that may never be used is wasteful, but that would depend on the design of your class.

Answer (score 1):

An object should be 100% ready for use after it's constructed.  Users should not have to be checking for nulls.  Defensive programming is the way to go - keep the checks.

In the interest of DRY, you can put the checks in the setters and simply have the constructor call them.  That way you don't code the checks twice.

Comment: be careful about calling setters from a constructor -- if a subclass overrides the setters, you can end up calling subclass code before the subclass has been initialized!

Comment: But if I'm in class A's constructor, and it calls its own setters, how does a subclass B overriding them matter?  "this" points to an instance of A, so I'd be calling A setters in its constructor, not B.  True?

Comment: @duffymo 'this' in a constructor always refers to the object being constructed. The static type of 'this' is the class in which it appears. The runtime type may be the same class or any subclass of that class.

Comment: What if the subclass overrides to add event support? The subclass setFoo() might call a propertyChangeSupport that has not yet been initialized, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if in one of your methods you set

```
itemMaster = null;
```

or you return a reference to the ItemManager to some other class and it sets itemMaster as null.
(You can guard against this easily return a clone of your ItemManager etc)

I would keep the checks as this is possible.

Comment: That null-setting is what I'm avoiding by design (as unwritten rule): no method will ever call "itemMaster = null"

Comment: And one can enforce resetting the reference (for mutable classes) by using final.

Comment: External code setting it's reference to itemMaster will have no effect.  It will just remove the local reference to the object.  It will not clear the object's internal reference or destruct the object.

Answer (score 0):

If it's all your code and you want to set that convention, it should be a nice thing to have. I agree with Paul's comment, though, that nothing prevents some errant code from accidentally setting one of your class variables to null. As a general rule, I always check for null. Yeah, it's a PITA, but defensive coding can be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the name of the class "ItemManager",  ItemManager sounds like a singleton in some app. If so you should investigate and really, really, know Dependency Injection. Use something like Spring ( http://www.springsource.org/ ) to create and inject the list of ItemComponentManagers into ItemManager.

Without DI, Initialization by hand in serious apps is a nightmare to debug and connecting up various "manager" classes to make narrow tests is hell.

Use DI always (even when constructing tests). For data objects, create a get() method that creates the list if it doesn't exist. However if the object is complex, almost certainly will find your life better using the Factory or Builder pattern and have the F/B set the member variables as needed.